# How to achieve non-throwing `MinBy` in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to achieve function that filters out some entry and take minimal value mapped by concrete function, and either return minimal value judged by it or get `null` when all elements are filtered out:

```cs
public readonly record struct PdfVerticalPos(float Raw_LessIsBelow)
{
}

public readonly record struct AxisAlignedRenderingBox
{
    public AxisAlignedRenderingBox(PdfVerticalPos upMost, PdfVerticalPos downMost, float leftMostRaw, float rightMostRaw)
    {
        this.UpMost = upMost;
        this.DownMost = downMost;
        this.LeftMost = leftMostRaw;
        this.RightMost = rightMostRaw;
    }
}

private static string? findTheBottomByCondition(IEnumerable<(AxisAlignedRenderingBox, string)> detectedStrings,
    float leftMostMin, float leftMostMax, Func<(AxisAlignedRenderingBox, string), bool> selectingPredicate)
{
    return detectedStrings
        .Where(selectingPredicate)
        .Where(tuple => leftMostMin <= tuple.Item1.LeftMost && tuple.Item1.LeftMost <= leftMostMax)
        .MinBy(tuple => tuple.Item1.UpMost.Raw_LessIsBelow).Item2;
}

internal void someCallSite() {
    var detectedStrings = whatever();
    var found = findTheBottomByCondition(detectedStrings, 60, 65,
                    tuple => tuple.Item1.UpMost.Raw_LessIsBelow >= baseY);
    // do whatever
}
```

However, when calling `MinBy`, it throws a `InvalidOperationException`. While I inspect the cause, I found that documentation said "it throws `InvalidOperationException` if `TSource` is a primitive type and the source sequence is empty." Not sure what it want to mean by "primitive type" since the Tuples are clearly not primitive type as [opposed to integers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types).

So I have rewrite the `findTheBottomByCondition` as follows:

```cs
private static string? findTheBottomByCondition(IEnumerable<(AxisAlignedRenderingBox, string)> detectedStrings,
    float leftMostMin, float leftMostMax, Func<(AxisAlignedRenderingBox, string), bool> selectingPredicate) {
    
    var valueTuples = detectedStrings.ToList();
    var a = valueTuples
            .Where(selectingPredicate)
            .Count(tuple => leftMostMin <= tuple.Item1.LeftMost && tuple.Item1.LeftMost <= leftMostMax);
    if (a > 0)
    {
        return valueTuples
            .Where(selectingPredicate)
            .Where(tuple => leftMostMin <= tuple.Item1.LeftMost && tuple.Item1.LeftMost <= leftMostMax)
            .MinBy(tuple => tuple.Item1.UpMost.Raw_LessIsBelow).Item2;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

While it's correctly working, but not-so-elegant to only avoiding the Exception. I want it to return `null` if it's not found regardless of if it is "primitive type", any ideas? I think I could achieve it by `catch`-ing `InvalidOperationException`, but I don't like that way, nor current mostly-copy-pasted and poor implementation.

Comment: How can the sequence be empty if it’s in the `a > 0` branch? Is your predicate nondeterministic, or is this already a working solution that you’d like to make cleaner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation ought to say that MinBy throws InvalidOperationException if `TSource` is a *non-nullable* type, not just a primitive type.

For MinBy to return `null` instead of throwing InvalidOperationException, the source sequence must support `null` values. You can use the Cast extension method to convert the tuples to nullable tuples:

```
.Where(...)
.Cast<(AxisAlignedRenderingBox, string)?>()
.MinBy(...)
```

Or you can define an extension method that infers the correct type:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource?> AsNullable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TSource : struct
    {
        return source.Cast<TSource?>();
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
.Where(...)
.AsNullable()
.MinBy(...)
```

Because the argument to MinBy is now a nullable tuple instead of just a tuple, you'll have to use the Value property:

```
.MinBy(tuple => tuple!.Value.Item1.UpMost.Raw_LessIsBelow)
```

And finally, since MinBy can now return `null`, you'll want to use the null-conditional `?.` operator before accessing the resulting tuple's Item2 property.